# Java User input related

Tags: java, string

I want to take input form user, i am sure my code is right but it don't work at all. Please help is there any thing that i am doing wrong?

```
`public void edit() throws IOException {
        sll.insertAfter();
        System.out.println("Enter text: ");
        String sen;
        sen = keyboard.next();
        Object obj = sen;
        sll.put(obj);
        }
```

when i execute this an error appears at this line

```
sen = keyboard.next();
```

Comment: Please submit your full code

Comment: "an error appears at this line" what error?

Comment: We can't help you much if you won't post error message you are getting (use [edit] option to add more info to your post). Also main purpose of stack overflow is to create searchable repository of programming questions and answers which could be found by others with similar problems. If you will not include in your question any information which will let them find your question it will not be useful for anyone (except you) which kind of makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Example 
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Edit();
   }


    public static void Edit()
    {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
       String random;
       System.out.print("Please input some text: ");
       random = scan.nextLine();
       System.out.println("You entered: " + random);
    }
}
```

I don't know what your main method looks like so I can only assume it's empty That being said  I can tell you why your current code doesn't work based off of the information you've given us.

1. Your edit method is not static, and in this situation assuming you've laid out your program simillar to this it must be static as it is in my example.
2. You've not setup a scanner, or maybe you did outside of your edit method but failed to make it static?

   ```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   ```

Why are you using Object, if you want to edit the string just use a for loop and substring.

```
    Object
```

If you provide us with more information, your full code and the error you're getting we can better help you!